# Blank page in chrome headless debugging mode

Tags: google-chrome, headless

I am on 13.6.1 (22G313) chrome version 120. When trying to start chrome headless in the the terminal:

dave@Davids-MBP ~ % chromec --headless=new --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-address=127.0.0.1 --remote-debugging-port=9223 https://www.google.com

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9223/devtools/browser/453bfeb7-9301-4898-b0bc-476fd9a78e23
```

When entering:

```
ws://127.0.0.1:9223/devtools/browser/453bfeb7-9301-4898-b0bc-476fd9a78e23
```

or

`127.0.0.1:9223`

in safari, I get a blank page.

What could be the error?

Answer (score 0):

calling dave@Davids-MBP ~ %

```
chromec --headless=new --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-address=127.0.0.1 --remote-debugging-port=9224  --ignore-ssl-errors --allow-insecure-localhost --window-size=1280,1000 --no-sandbox --remote-allow-origins=http://127.0.0.1:9224 https://www.google.com
```

calling the url in Firefox:

```
http://127.0.0.1/json
```

and from there there calling the correct url did solved the problem:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9224/devtools/inspector.html?ws=127.0.0.1:9224/devtools/page/4AF1EDB1D82A95D644C51EDED1A62BC0
```